# Нужно, чтобы изображения в LightBox сортировались бы вместе с их превью

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Есть страница с множеством тематических фото. С помощью меню я их фильтрую (Isotope) по темам в том же самом окне. Проблема в том, что сортируются только превьюшки. Когда же открывается галерея LightBox (реализовано с помощью [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#basic)), там ничего не отфильтровано, шпарит все фотки подряд. Должно получиться вот так: [галерея](http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/plugins/mediaBoxes/example/gallery.html#) Что посоветуете?
Ниже меню:

```
<div id="button_group" class="filters-button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">USA</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".oc">Orange</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".sf">San Fran</button>
</div>
```

Далее контент:

```
<section class="main clearfix">
    <ul id="grid" class="gridy isotope" >
        <li><a href="images/big/tile1.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile1.jpg" class="element-item oc"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/big/tile2.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile2.jpg" class="element-item sf"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/big/tile3.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile3.jpg" class="element-item oc"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/big/tile4.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile4.jpg" class="element-item sf"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/big/tile7.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile7.jpg" class="element-item oc"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/big/tile8.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption"><img src="images/thumbs/tile8.jpg" class="element-item sf"></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Вот JS на фильтрацию:

```js
$(function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('#grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    // show if number is greater than 50

    // show if name ends with -ium

  };
  // bind filter button click
  $('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: filterValue
    });
  });
  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button_group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
    var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
    $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});
```

И код Лайтбокс:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button_group li.has-sub > a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
      element.removeClass('open');
      element.find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.find('ul').slideUp();
    } else {
      element.addClass('open');
      element.children('ul').slideDown();
      element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
      element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
  });

  $('#button_group>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');
});
```